# What does Conda do while collecting metadata?

Tags: python, conda

When a new environment is created with Conda, the very first step is `Collecting package metadata (repodata.json)`, followed by `Solving environment`.

What does Conda really do during the first step: is it just fetching from the Anaconda Cloud repositories the dependencies of each package listed in my `environment.yml` file?

Depending on the `environment.yml` file, step 1 can sometimes take very long: is there a way to figure out which package in `environment.yml` slows down the process of creating the environment?

Comment: Nonetheless an interesting question, but for practical purposes, users with speed concerns should consider switching to Mamba.

Comment: related: https://www.anaconda.com/blog/understanding-and-improving-condas-performance